# Connect to an access point on Android 10 (without internet)

Tags: android, wifi

maybe someone can help me.

I want to connect to an access point and do an httpRquest. My code worked until last week. I did an update for my phone. I have android 10. This is my code:

```
                WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
                builder.setSsid(accessPoint);
                builder.setWpa2Passphrase(PASSWORD);
                WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();
                NetworkRequest.Builder networkbuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

                networkbuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
                networkbuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);

                NetworkRequest nr = networkbuilder.build();

                cm.requestNetwork(nr, callback);`
```

When Android has done the requestNetwork Method it gets NO NetworkCallback and the phone shows: No devices found. Make sure that the device is on and available.

Can please someone help me out?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.
The password was wrong formated. A "-sign was at the end of the string.
The problem was, that android don't says that the password is wrong, but says that no network is available.